# Android implement navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I am trying to learn Android development and have stumbled across the following thing I cannot solve.

I have imported [Bottom Bar Navigation](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) via Gradle to my app and have managed to set it up according to instructions. Here is what my screen looks like now.

[image]

As you can see, I have three tabs at the bottom that I am trying to use for navigation. The problem however is, that even though I know how to detect which element has been clicked via following:

```
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottombar_menu, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bb_menu_favorites) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bb_menu_favorites) {
                // The user reselected item number one, scroll your content to top.
            }
        }
    });
```

I have no idea how to actually perform the navigation request - e.g. when user moves to different tab, I want to show my other screen instead of `Hello World!` that you can see at the moment.

I believe that for this I need to actually change my `activity_main.xml` file as currently it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    tools:context="com.example.robert.testproject.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/page_import"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is where I have ended. As far as my understanding goes, I somehow need to use `Intent` (correct me if I am wrong) for the navigation purposes, but I am not quite sure how to handle this.

Any help in this matter - switching views, would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Fragment for each bottom tab (3 Fragments for 3 views). Have a container layout(maybe a FrameLayout) in the Activity. Each Fragment will have different layouts. Replace the fragments based on what the user has tapped on the bottom bar.